# Initiate bash script on shutdown, but not on reboot

Tags: systemd, shutdown

I'm setting up my Linux box (that is connected to a UPS) to gracefully shutdown my pfsense router prior to shutting down.  I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, and using systemd to accomplish this.  I have the systemd service configured, and it works. However, it's initiating the script on shutdown AND on reboot.  This is no good since anytime I reboot my linux box, I'll be shutting down my router.  How can I change my systemd service so that it only activates during shutdown?

My setup is as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=PFSense Shutdown script
After=poweroff.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/path/to/script/pfsenseshutdown.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And, for reference, the pfsenseshutdown.sh script is fairly simple:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@x.x.x.x -i "sudo /etc/rc.halt"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may want to add this to `WantedBy=shtudown.target` instead of `WantedBy=multi-user.target`. I think you also have to change the `ExecStart` and `ExecStop` assignments.

Comment: OK...I'll try the WantedBy statement in a bit.  I'm not sure what you mean by the ExecStart/Stop assignments.  What do you think they need to be changed to?

Comment: Not really sure, but I think your script has to be assigned to `ExecStart=/path/to/script/pfsenseshutdown.sh`.

Comment: Perhaps you can hook into the reboot sequence with another script that writes something to a file in `/dev/shm/` (is a memory file system, and is cleared when you boot). In the `pfsenseshutdown.sh` script you could then look for that file to see if it's a reboot or shutdown.

Comment: brm...sounds promising.  I'm still learning systemd....and bash for that matter....so I'm not entirely sure how to go about that.

Answer (score 3):

The following approach seems to run a script on shutdown only, and not on reboot. You can edit the `systemd-poweroff.service` file as follows:

```
sudo systemctl edit --full systemd-poweroff.service
```

In the `[Service]` section, you can then add an `ExecStartPre` line:

```
ExecStartPre=/path/to/script/pfsenseshutdown.sh
```

This way, the script will not be executed if you shutdown the system with `halt` however. To handle this case, you can add the same line to `systemd-halt.service`.

Note that in this approach the config file shown in the question is not used.

**EDIT:** a possible shortcoming in the previous approach, is that the script to be executed contains an `ssh` command, which may not work right before shutting down the system (systemd may already have stopped necessary network services). The approach below tries to avoid this.

For this solution, I created a `pfsenseshutdown.service` unit with the following contents

```
[Unit]
Description=PFSense Shutdown script
DefaultDedendencies=no

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/touch /dev/shm/shuttingdown

[Install]
WantedBy=systemd-halt.service systemd-poweroff.service
```

When starting the shutdown procedure, this file seems to cause the `ExecStart` line to be executed right away, causing the file `/dev/shm/shuttingdown` to exist (the `/dev/shm` directory is a memory file system, so it will be cleared after a reboot).

Now, to make sure that your script is executed before the network is completely de-initialized, I ran

```
systemctl edit --full networking.service
```

Originally, it contained the following `ExecStop` line on my ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine:

```
ExecStop=/sbin/ifdown -a --read-environment
```

This line was replaced by a version that first runs your script, in this example:

```
ExecStop=/path/to/script/pfsenseshutdown.sh && /sbin/ifdown -a --read-environment
```

The `pfsenseshutdown.sh` script, then tests if the file in `/dev/shm` exists, and performs the ssh command accordingly. I also added a small `sleep` command: systemd does many things in parallel, and this hopefully helps prevent the test from failing because the file does not exist *yet*.

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 1

if [ -e /dev/shm/shuttingdown ] ; then

    # Your ssh command here

fi
```

Comment: No dice.  I edited the systemd-poweroff.service to include the ExecStartPre command, but it's not executing the script.  Actually...the linux box is halting at the "Reached target Shutdown", and will not actually power off.  I know the script path works, because if works fine in original systemd service.  Is there a way to shutdown more verbosely to see what it's choking on?

Comment: Maybe there's a difference in how the shutdown is initiated? I'm testing using a virtual machine, and if I just type 'halt' at the command line, I get the same behavior that you mention: the "Reached target Shutdown" message is shown, but the script is not executed and the VM doesn't really power off. On the other hand, I can also initiate shutdown by selecting "shutdown" in the GUI, and then the script is executed and the system powers off

Comment: I did some more experiments and made a slight addition to the answer (about editing `systemd-halt.service` as well). Can you try again?

Comment: Thanks for helping out, brm...but still no luck.  I've added the ExecStartPre line to both systemd-shutdown.service and systemd-halt.service.  However, each time I enter "sudo shutdown now", it stops at the "Reached target Shutdown" message and never powers off.  It also does not execute the pfsenseshutdown script.  I did notice that the status of the halt and shutdown services says "Active: inactive (dead)"...but I'm not sure if that matters or not.  Any other advice?

Comment: And just for comparison, I commented out the ExecStartPre command in both services, and entered 'sudo shutdown now', and the box powered down normally.  So, there does seem to be something about the ExecStartPre line that's causing issues.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps the shutdown procedure did something to the network status, not allowing you to run ssh successfully anymore. In that case, your script is actually executed, but because ssh doesn't work correctly anymore (and takes a while to notice this), the shutdown seems to hang. Could you try adding a line above the ssh command that writes something to a file, to see if it is executed? That works in my VM...

Comment: The plot thickens.  I added a line to create a file and write to it...and that part works.  So your theory regarding network status may be correct.  Any idea how to get around it?

Comment: Perhaps you can add some extra ExecStartPre lines to start the necessary network processes again. A clean way would require a better knowledge of systemd than I possess I'm afraid.

Comment: After some testing, I came up with another possible solution. Hope this works...

Comment: @cgram Just a message in case you didn't notice I added something

Comment: I did see that, thanks.  I've been tied up and haven't been able to test.  I plan to give it a shot tonight or tomorrow.